# How to combine dataframes based on index column name

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I am new to python and I have 2 dfs and a list of tickers and i would like to combine the 2 dfs based on a list of tickers. My second df had the tickers imported from an excel sheet and so the column names in the index are in a different order, I am not sure if that changes anything.

df1 looks like

### df1

| index | ABC | DEF | XYZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| avg | 2 | 6 | 12 |
| std | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| var | 24 | 25 | 35 |
| max | 56 | 66 | 78 |

### df 2

| index | 10 | 40 | 96 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ticker | XYZ | ABC | DEF |
| Sector | Auto | Tech | Mining |

I would like to combine them based on their ticker names in a third `df` with all the information so it looks something like this

### df3

| index | ABC | DEF | XYZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| avg | 2 | 6 | 12 |
| std | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| var | 24 | 25 | 35 |
| max | 56 | 66 | 78 |
| Sector | Tech | Mining | Auto |

I have tried this

```
df3= pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)
```

but it made a `df` where they were side by side instead of in one combine `df`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the index

```
df2 = df2.set_index('index').T.set_index('ticker').T
out = pd.concat([df1,df2])
         ABC     DEF   XYZ
index                     
avg        2       6    12
std        1       2     3
var       24      25    35
max       56      66    78
Sector  Tech  Mining  Auto
```